# Was this move to superuser correct?

Tags: discussion, migration

Regarding the question: [How to restore Eclipse shortcut keys from exported .CSV?](https://superuser.com/questions/718404/how-to-restore-eclipse-shortcut-keys-from-exported-csv)

This question came up in the close queue, and while I understand the "this is not programming, this is just using software" knee-jerk, I think asking would fall clearly under

- *software tools commonly used by programmers*

and I believe shouldn't have been moved. Do you agree, and if not, why not, and if so: can we/I do something? Playing bounce-the-question is hardly something we need :)

Comment: Well, since it has already been moved, the only thing we can do is bounce the question over once more time...

Comment: And frankly, it is a good question for SU as well, so... why not just let it stay?

Comment: Well, for one thing the OP doesn't seem to be an active SU asker, so I'm not sure this will help the OP. Now that's hardly the only thing we look at, but as long as we do "software tools" on SO, it's the better fit (I mean, it looks like // I think it is), isn't it? As in, I thought that when multiple sites were available the 'tightest' fit would be the one to go for?

Comment: Sure, but now that 5 community members have decided to migrate it, surely bouncing it back will only confuse matters further?

Comment: True, so maybe the underlying issue is the clarity of the 'software tools' rule. Maybe this question is escalating to "what to do when the rules don't match the community // the community doesn't know the rules" (try formulating that without finger-pointing :) .. isn't meant as such, but hard to think of a better way to formulate )